# Query msdb sysjobhistory and join to the failed package on Integration Services Catalog

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I currently have a query that pulls data on failed jobs from msdb sysjobhistory.
This works well but the error message of why the package failed is not useful as it sends me to the Integration Services Catalog for the error message. I would prefer to have one query that gets the job name, the failed step and the reason why it failed.

I use the query below to get the failed jobs.Please can you help me to finish the query.

```
USE MSDB
GO

SELECT j.name JobName,h.step_name StepName, 
--CONVERT(CHAR(10), CAST(STR(h.run_date,8, 0) AS dateTIME), 111) AS RunDate, 
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), h.run_date, 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( h.run_time AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':'), 108)) AS RunDate,
--h.run_date,
STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( h.run_time AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS RunTime, 
STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( h.run_duration AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS RunDuration, 
STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( h.run_duration AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS StepDuration,
case h.run_status when 0 then 'Failed'
when 1 then 'Succeded' 
when 2 then 'Retry' 
when 3 then 'Cancelled' 
when 4 then 'In Progress' 
end as ExecutionStatus, 
h.message MessageGenerated,
    H.Server
    --INTO Maintenance.dbo.Intergration_Logs
    FROM sysjobhistory h inner join sysjobs j
    ON j.job_id = h.job_id
    --WHERE h.run_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112)
```

Comment: Why both MySQL and MS SQL Server tags? Please, do not tag products not involved...

Comment: Sorry just trying to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

The information about why a job failed is stored in sysjobhistory.

If you're looking for something that just gets straight to the point and gives you the bare bones of what you need to know when a job failed (job name, the failed step and the reason why it failed), something like this might work:

```
WITH T1 AS (SELECT [job_id], [instance_id], [message]
    FROM sysjobhistory
    WHERE run_status = 0 AND step_name = '(Job Outcome)')
, T2 AS (SELECT [job_id], [instance_id]
    FROM T1
    WHERE [message] NOT LIKE '%the last step to run was%'
    UNION
    SELECT jh.[job_id], jh.[instance_id]
    FROM  sysjobhistory jh
    JOIN T1 ON T1.[instance_id] - 1 = jh.[instance_id]
    WHERE T1.[message] LIKE '%the last step to run was%')
SELECT j.[name], jh.[step_id], jh.[step_name], jh.[message]
FROM sysjobs j
JOIN sysjobhistory jh ON jh.[job_id] = j.[job_id]
JOIN T2 ON T2.[instance_id] = jh.[instance_id]
```